# Data Profiling using python

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a data frame as below :

```
 member_id  |   loan_amnt   |  Age   | Marital_status
 AK219      |    49539.09   |  34    |  Married 
 AK314      |    1022454.00 |  37    |  NA
 BN204      |    75422.00   |  34    |  Single
```

I want to create an output file in the below format

```
 Columns       | Null Values | Duplicate |
 member_id     |  N          |   N       |
 loan_amnt     |  N          |   N       |
 Age           |  N          |   Y       |
 Marital Status|  Y          |   N       |
```

I know about one python package called `PandasProfiling` but I want build this in the above manner so that I can enhance my code with respect to the data sets.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: @Ruturaj- I ran python package `PandasProfiling` ,it gave me the details about Null values , duplicate values, Maximum , min values. But I want to build this by my own. I need to enhance this further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like:

```
m=df.apply(lambda x: x.duplicated())
n=df.isna()
df_new=(pd.concat([pd.Series(n.any(),name='Null_Values'),pd.Series(m.any(),name='Duplicates')],axis=1)
                     .replace({True:'Y',False:'N'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is python one-liner:

`pd.concat([df.isnull().any() , df.apply(lambda x: x.count() != x.nunique())], 1).replace({True: "Y", False: "N"})`

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Pandas_Profiling gives you multiple options where you can figure out if there are repetitive values.